# Run code after view has loaded

Tags: objective-c

got a problem with my project. Views are taking forever to open, because i'm downloading information from a database, and when i click a button to open new view, its loading all info from database and populating table cells before the view opens, and then opens the view.

I want it to open the view, show a loading symbol, and then load the data into the table, any tips?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into doing stuff in the background. [This link should get you going.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Use the -(void)viewDidAppear:animated method to display your loading symbol then start the downloads.

Although you should be doing it in the background.